# setTimeout executing is not stopping further iterations from occurring - need other solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a typing game using just jQuery and javascript. It worked fine as a single player game, feel free to play it at http://typetothestars.bitballoon.com/ However, I am planning to keep ratcheting up its complexity level. So I am trying to add muti player to it now.

here it is in jsfiddle minus images https://jsfiddle.net/u32s4yty/

My problem lies in my runRace functions. I was expecting the race to run for player 1, when the interval ended, it would then start again for player 2. Instead, it runs through all the iterations right away. So apperently setTimeout is not going to work here.

Any suggestions as to how to make it work?

Thanks!

```
// ** RUNNING GAME FUNCTIONS ** \\

//hides instructions and reveals game
function setupRace(i) {
  console.log("In Race Setup")
  $("#word").show();
  document.getElementById("word").focus();
  generateWords();
  $(".toType").text(gameWords[0]);
  $("#instructions").hide();
  $(".wordDisplay").show();
  $(".player").show();
  var playerAvatar = 'url("images/' + playerInfo[i].avatar + '.png")'
  $(".player").css({background: playerAvatar});
}

//game timer - IS NOT STOPPING THE OTHER FUNCTIONS FROM RUNNING
var timeoutID;
function timer(i) {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(checkEndRace, 3000, i)
  console.log("i = " + i);
  console.log(playerInfo[i]);
}

function checkEndRace(i) {
  console.log("in check end race - num players " + numPlayers);
  if (i < numPlayers - 1) {
    setupRace(i);
  }else {
    endRace(i);
  }
}

//advances ship on correct typing
function runRace() {
  console.log("In run race");
  var i = 0;
  while (i < playerInfo.length) {
    console.log("in run race loop");
    setupRace(i);
    timer(i);
    //timer is skipping ahead to the next iteration, eventhough 
    //checkEndRace hasn't run yet
    var j = 1;
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
      var targetWord = $(".toType").text();
      var typedWord = $("#word").val();
      while (j < gameWords.length){
        if(typedWord === targetWord){
          $(".player").css({left: "+=15px",});
          targetWord = $(".toType").text(gameWords[j]);
          $("#word").val("");
          j++;
        }else {
          return
        };
      }
    });
    i ++;
  };
}
```

I was hoping to use setTimeout to stop all functions the following functions, until the interval is completed.

Comment: All your timeouts are run in 3 seconds, instead of having the first one at the 3 second mark, the second one at the 6 second mark, etc.

Comment: Use promises and execute the functions after whatever it is you wait for has resolved?

Comment: @MinusFour - ahhhh, that makes sense, although the next iterations in the runRace function happen prior to the timeinterval anyways, but that would explain why the alert in the endRace function fires of, as many times as there are players in the game at the end of the 3 secs

Comment: Timeout functions run asynchronously. When you call it, it doesn't wait for it to complete.

Comment: @Barmar, yeah, i figured that out. what would be an alternate solution instead of using setTimeout. I want to halt all operation until the time interval ends and then proced down the logic path

Answer (score 0):

Calls to setTimeout return immediately and only execute once so one easy/common way to handle ordering them is to make tail calls (tick) to setTimeout and to put all requests in a queue.

```
// ** RUNNING GAME FUNCTIONS ** \\

var raceHandlers = [];
var raceTimout = 3000;

function tick() {
  // Tail call
  if (raceHandlers.length > 0) {
     var action = raceHandlers.pop();
     setTimeout(action[0],raceTimeout,action[1]);
  }
}

//hides instructions and reveals game
function setupRace(i) {
  console.log("In Race Setup")
  $("#word").show();
  document.getElementById("word").focus();
  generateWords();
  $(".toType").text(gameWords[0]);
  $("#instructions").hide();
  $(".wordDisplay").show();
  $(".player").show();
  var playerAvatar = 'url("images/' + playerInfo[i].avatar + '.png")'
  $(".player").css({background: playerAvatar});
  tick();
}

//advances ship on correct typing
function runRace() {
  console.log("In run race");
  var i = 0;
  while (i < playerInfo.length) {
    console.log("in run race loop");
    //setupRace(i);
    raceHandlers.unshift([setupRace,i]);

    //timer is skipping ahead to the next iteration, eventhough 
    //checkEndRace hasn't run yet
    var j = 1;
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
      var targetWord = $(".toType").text();
      var typedWord = $("#word").val();
      while (j < gameWords.length){
        if(typedWord === targetWord){
          $(".player").css({left: "+=15px",});
          targetWord = $(".toType").text(gameWords[j]);
          $("#word").val("");
          j++;
        }else {
          return
        };
      }
    });
    i ++;
  };

  raceHandlers.unshift([endRace,playerInfo.length]);
  tick();
}
```